# Excel or Google Sheets: Return a value based on change in a variable

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have two columns with variables A to E.  I would like to calculate the change in those values.  For example, if A1 is "A" and A2 is "D" the change is +3.  If A1 is "D" and A2 is "A" the change is -3.  What function can I use to calculate this?

Thanks in advance for the ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel you'd use

```
=CODE(A2) - CODE(A1)
```

Comment: Works in Google Sheets too! Thanks